# Can this be written as a derivative at a point?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We have the following ratio : 
$$\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct-r)}{2r}$$
as $r \to 0 $ can we say that $\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct-r)}{2r}$ tends to the derivative of $f$ at some point (possibly times a constant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. If $f$ is differentiable at $ct$ then 
$$f'(ct)=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f(ct+r) - f(ct)}{r}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f(ct-r) - f(ct)}{-r}.$$
Note that if $f(x)=|x|$ then $f$ is not differentiable at $t=0$  but the given limit exists:
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct-r)}{2r}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|r| - |-r|}{2r}=0.$$

Comment: Note, though, that the original limit may exist even if these two limits do not exist independently.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, I was writing a P.S. just to mention this case.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable, simply note that

$$\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct-r)}{2r}=\frac12\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct)}{r}
-\frac12\frac{f(ct-r)-f(ct)}{r}=\\=\frac12\frac{f(r+ct) - f(ct)}{r}
+\frac12\frac{f(ct-r)-f(ct)}{-r}$$

then apply the definition of derivative.

As an alternative, we can use that

- $f(ct+r)=f(ct)+f'(ct)\cdot r+o(r)$
- $f(ct-r)=f(ct)-f'(ct)\cdot r+o(r)$

with $\frac{o(r)}{r} \to 0$ as $r\to 0$.

Note that the given limit can exist also if $f$ is not differentiable at $r=0$ (e.g. $y=|x|$).

Answer (score 2):

$(1/2)\dfrac{(f(ct+r) -f(ct))}{r} +(1/2)\dfrac{ (f(ct-r) -f(ct))}{(-r)}.$

Assuming the individual limits exist:

The limit $r \rightarrow 0$ is?

Note :  Michael Seifert's comment.